# Power IC heating, laptop is not starting

Tags: power-supply, battery, acer-aspire

I'm using Acer aspire E5-473G-3100.

Today, when I tried to turn on my laptop, it said **Media test failure, check cable**.

I opened my laptop, disconnected HDD and connected again then tried turning on, it turned on. So I turned it off, disconnected battery, done some cleaning(removed visible dust using cotton cloth very carefully, no connection broken/damaged) and reconnected the battery.

Don't know what went wrong, but one of the IC started heating. I tried turning the laptop on, not work. No LED indicator is turning on.

I tried disconnecting the battery, the IC stopped heating. And started heating again when the battery is connected. IC is extremely hot. I cannot touch it even for 1 second.

Checked for IC label, it is `ITE IT8887E`. When I googled for it, I found it is **power IC chip**.

What I searched for solutions, I found [this](https://my.answers.acer.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/34842/~/acer-internal-battery-reset) on the Acer forum. I tried this but not worked.

If anyone can help me to resolve this problem, please.

Thanks.

Comment: Define "some cleaning". What exactly did you clean? Using what tools or chemicals?

Comment: By cleaning, i mean removing dust using  only cotton.

Comment: Removing dust where? Cleaning what exactly? What did you actually *do*? Did you dismantle anything? Did you move connectors? Are you certain they are properly fitted again? How do you know one chip is getting hot? Can you see it or only feel it? You can [edit] your question to add details.

Comment: Are any of the USB connectors damaged? Unplug anything connected to the laptop. (dongles, mouse, etc).

Comment: @ChristopherHostage It would appear that simply reconnecting the hard disk fixed the error so that it is an incidental prior event that led to a maintenance and cleaning process. It is after this unspecified cleaning event (third paragraph, computer now apparently fine) where OP found out that they had done some damage. At this point it appears we need to know what they "cleaned", though minimally I would suggest that cotton is not the best for cleaning static sensitive components.

Comment: @Mokubai I have removed visible dust using cotton cloth very carefully, no connection broken/damaged. While cleaning, I have removed only HDD, Battery, and RAM. I have connected each of them properly. When I found that the laptop is not turning on, I tried to remove and reconnect HDD. The Power IC is near to HDD and my hand touched it while reconnecting HDD. This way I found that it is started heating and then I disconnected the battery, it became normal. Connecting adapter/battery again results in heating.

Comment: It is possible that in removing the hard drive or memory you damaged one of the connectors or have bent a pin while reinserting the HDD. Remove everything again, see if the problem persists and *carefully* examine connectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got it checked at the service center. They said CPU is shot, mother-board needs to be replaced, which costs almost half the price of the laptop I bought.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible your hard drive failed. In bios setup you need to change the boot options. Try to set the boot order as hdd first and see if that works. Or try various hard drive boot settings, ahci, legacy, raid. If that doesn't work you can try to disable secure boot. Media test failure means windows failed to boot and tried to boot from network and that also failed.

Comment: the board is not working at all.